# Sending form data with ajax echo data with php not displaying

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im learning Ajax...normally I dont like posting about a subject I know very little of but I believe Im on the right path here (maybe not...?) so I will take a chance to find out.

Ive got 3 select boxes each box populates with values based on the the selection of the box before it:

[image]

Everything is working perfectly, **when the user clicks submit** I want to send the 3 textbox values to 3 php variables and echo it on the same page...

Now my data is not echoing (the data of the variables are not displaying) but when I look in my console on firefox I can see the value of the variables...

**Here is the selection made on the select boxes**

[image]

**Here is what im seeing in my console**

[image]

Yet it is does not echo on the page....?

```
jQuery(document).click(function(e){
    var self = jQuery(e.target);
    if(self.is("#resultForm input[type=submit], #form-id input[type=button], #form-id button")){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = self.closest('form'), formdata = form.serialize();
        //add the clicked button to the form data
        if(self.attr('name')){
            formdata += (formdata!=='')? '&':'';
            formdata += self.attr('name') + '=' + ((self.is('button'))? self.html(): self.val());
        }
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr("action"), 
            data: formdata, 
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**PHP below form**

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
   $sport = $_POST['sport'];
   $round = $_POST['round'];
   $tournament=$_POST['tournament'];

   echo $sport;
   echo $round;
   echo $tournament;

}
```

Comment: in your `success: function(data) { }` all you are doing is `console.log(data);` -> `success: function(data) { console.log(data); }`. You need to add your method in there, ie. `success: function(data) {  $('#resultForm').append(data); }`, where `$('#resultForm')` could be any page element to append to.

Comment: @Sean Thank you if you post as answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in your code that would make the values display on the page. You would need to either do some DOM insertion in your AJAX success function, or do a full page refresh and echo the data out via PHP (but that would probably defeat the purpose of doing an AJAX call in the first place.)

If you want to go the AJAX route, I would suggest editing your PHP to the following:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'sport' => $sport,
    'round' => $round,
    'tournament' => $tournament
));
```

This will return a JSON object for your jQuery AJAX call to consume.

In your jQuery success function, do something with those values, like so:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: form.attr("action"), 
    data: formdata, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('<div></div>').text(data.sport).appendTo('body');
        $('<div></div>').text(data.round).appendTo('body');
        $('<div></div>').text(data.tournament).appendTo('body');
    }
});
```

Note the additional `dataType` argument to `$.ajax`. To do it the *right* way, you'll also want to set your headers in your PHP response to "application/json"

Comment: You can set the header in PHP like this: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0):

You ajax is just displaying the output in console. Change the ajax success to display it in page. 
Make changes after success as:

```
success:function(data){
$('someelementclassorid').text(data);
}
```